# when doing dividing operations in pandas, i always get 'NAN' results. how can I solve the problem?

Tags: python, pandas, nan, calculation, divide

I want to make column 'ratio' that is the result after each value of the column 'amount' divides the last value of the column 'amount'. the data type of amount column is int64. After changing the data type to float, I also got the same 'NAN' value.

[image]

Comment: [Please don't post pictures of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341). Instead, copy the text itself, [edit] it into your post, and use the formatting tools like [code formatting](/editing-help#code).

Comment: Also, if the `user_input` isn't relevant to the problem -- and it doesn't seem to be -- don't bother including it. For reference, see [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do any math on several data frames or sequences, Pandas aligns on indexes and columns by default. `tail(1)` returns not a single value (scalar) but a sequence *with the last index of the original data*. When you divide the column on the obtained sequence, data are merged on indexes and then divided on corresponding values. Since tail contains only the value with the last index, the merge ends up with `nan` values as corresponding divisors for all dividends except the last one. That's why you got `nan` everywhere except at the last position.

To avoid this behavior, pass the divisor either as a number or a `numpy.array`.
In this case, it can be

```
dt['amount'] / dt['amount'].tail(1).values    # divide on a numpy.array
dt['amount'] / dt['amount'].iloc[-1]          # divide on a number
```

Comment: Very well explained! Another option is `.iat`, which works just like `.iloc` but makes it clear you're getting a single value. Personally, I wouldn't use `tail` for this, but maybe that's just my preference.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `tail` specify the location of the last value:

```
df['amount'] / df['amount'].iloc[-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) like this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'amount': range(4,8), 'user_input': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']}

dt = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

dt
# Out: 
#    amount user_input
# 0       4          a
# 1       5          b
# 2       6          c
# 3       7          d

dt['ratio'] = dt['amount']/dt['amount'].shift(1)

dt
# Out: 
#    amount user_input     ratio
# 0       4          a       NaN
# 1       5          b  1.250000
# 2       6          c  1.200000
# 3       7          d  1.166667
```

Note that if you have a division by zero you will get an `inf` and of course the first value in the `'ratio'` column is undefined.

Comment: I think OP meant "last" as in "final", not "previous".

Comment: @wjandrea thanks, you're right! I hadn't thought about it

Answer (score 0):

A different take of same approach:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'col1': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'],
    'col2': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
}

# Convert data into DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.assign(new_col = df['col2']/df['col2'].values[-1])
print(df)
```